# Registration form won't display input

Tags: php, forms, registration

I am making a registration form and have made some simple php to process the email as a test:

```
    Hello  <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
```

I am using the post method, and although the atom editor was displaying the Hello, it doesn't display the email.

And in case anyone needs it, here is the html I am using:

```
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" 
    required>

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw- 
    repeat" 
    required>
    <hr>
    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & 
    Privacy</a>.</p>

    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container signin">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in</a>.</p>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works fine, please make sure you echoing `Hello  <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>` in `welcome.php`
if yes make sure you have php installed.

Comment: Thanks for telling me this, I don't think I have PHP installed. How can I install it?

Comment: try installing xampp or wamp if you working on windows.

Comment: Also, might I be working on the wrong platform? I don't know whether atom supports PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error. If you place the php code provided in above in welcome.php, and you fill the form, email is displayed properly after Hello. There migh